# Error regarding list traceback function

Tags: python, list

I am trying to return the elements starting from the last row which are equal to 1 and not zero.And then traceback the next element by comparing with adjacent elements vertically,horizontally and diagonally.if next element is zero,then return the position,else continue till we reach a position where the next element will be zero and hence return the position.
I have written the following program:

```
def test():
        M=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]

            list=[]

for i in range(2,0,-1):
    for j in range(6,0,-1):
        if M[i,j]!=0 and M[i,j]<=k:
            s=max(M[i,j-1],M[i-1,j-1],M[i-1,j])
            if s==0:
                list.append(j+1)
            else:
                s=M[i,j]
        elif j==0:
            for i in range(2,0,-1):
                if M[i,j]!=0 and M[i,j]<=k:
                    s=M[i-1,j]
                    if s==0:
                        list.append(j+1)
                    else:
                        s=M[i,j]
return list
    print(test())
Expected answer will be 1,4,7
```

It returned me values 4,7 but 1 is not showing,can anyone suggest me the additions that it returns me the value '1' as well ?I have tried editing the code,but still it shows the same result.

Comment: Index `i` is the row - valid values [0, 1,2] and index `j` is the column valid values are [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 ]

Comment: Your `M` list is a [3x7] 2-D list, correct i,j ranges ...

Comment: @jhilmer it is showing me now this error : if M[i,j]!=0 and M[i,j]<=k:
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Comment: Thanks I modified the code with your changes,but it isn't giving me the other values which are also required.How to return all the values ?

Comment: Collect all your good values in a list (instead of returning mid-loop), and return that list at the end of the function.

Comment: It is working,although it is not returning 1 as one of the values.